# Whats wrong with this typeahead.js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

typeahead.js and jquery, using example from typeahead.js. Scripts all seem to be loading correctly, but nothing happens when typing in the input.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='typeahead.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js'></script>

<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="stuff" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;">

<script>
  $(function(){

        $('.typeahead').typeahead({                              
          name: 'twitter-oss',                                                        
          prefetch: './repos.json',                                             
          template: [                                                                 
            '<p class="repo-language">{{language}}</p>',                              
            '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',                                      
            '<p class="repo-description">{{description}}</p>'                         
          ].join(''),                                                                 
          engine: Hogan                                                               
        });
  })
</script>

// repos.json
[
  {"name":"Joe", "description":"Person", "language":"en"}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out typeahead documentation (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum).

The individual units that compose datasets are called `datums`. The canonical form of a datum is an object with a `value` property and a `tokens` property. The `value` is the string that represents the underlying value of the datum and `tokens` is a collection of strings that aid *typeahead.js* in matching datums with a given query.

So your json item should have the following structure:

```
{
 "name":"Joe", 
 "description":"Person", 
 "language":"en",
 "value" : "Joe",
 "tokens" : ['Joe']
}
```